# Opening wav from URL in Python

Tags: python, pyaudio, wave

With the Python script shown below I try to play a wav file from the internet but I'm getting the error message `OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: 'https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav'`.

How can I play a wav file from the internet?

```
import pyaudio
import wave

chunk = 1024

f = wave.open("https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav","rb")
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format = p.get_format_from_width(f.getsampwidth()),
                channels = f.getnchannels(),
                rate = f.getframerate(),
                output = True)
data = f.readframes(chunk)

while data:
    stream.write(data)
    data = f.readframes(chunk)

stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()

p.terminate()
```

Comment: You will probably need to download the file first and then play it. `wave.open` only knows how to operate on local files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also get the content of website, store it in a variable, and play it. There is no need to store it on the disk for a short file like this. Here is an example of how to do this:

```py
import logging

import requests
import simpleaudio

sample_rate = 8000
num_channels = 2
bytes_per_sample = 2

total = sample_rate * num_channels * bytes_per_sample

logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

audio_url = "https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav"

logging.info(f"Downloading audio file from: {audio_url}")
content = requests.get(audio_url).content

# Just to ensure that the file does not have extra bytes
blocks = len(content) // total
content = content[:total * blocks]

wave = simpleaudio.WaveObject(audio_data=content,
                              sample_rate=sample_rate,
                              num_channels=num_channels,
                              bytes_per_sample=bytes_per_sample)
control = wave.play()
control.wait_done()
```

Comment: i'm wondering, `content[:total * blocks]` no need consider the wav header bytes?

Comment: yeah, sure, the right way would be to do that. This is just a quick hack to ensure the audio will play. In the ideal solution, the metadata about the .wav file should be extracted from the binary content and used in the object instantiation.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what when I don't know the sample_rate, num_channels and bytes_per_sample? How can I extract the metadata as you suggested?

Comment: the header must be splitted according to [header specification](https://isip.piconepress.com/projects/speech/software/tutorials/production/fundamentals/v1.0/section_02/s02_01_p05.html). Maybe there is a library to do this in a simpler way, otherwise the approach is more low level, the [struct module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/struct.html) may help

Answer (score 1):

I'm demonstrating what @larsks suggests.

```py
import requests

with open(audio_file, 'wb') as a:
    resp = requests.get("https://file-examples-com.github.io/uploads/2017/11/file_example_WAV_1MG.wav")
    if resp.status_code == 200:
        a.write(resp.content)
        print('downloaded')
    else:
        print(resp.reason)
        exit(1)

f = wave.open(audio_file, "rb")


# the remaining lines are the same
```

And I also suggest another great python library [python-mpv](https://github.com/jaseg/python-mpv) which is based on [mpv](https://github.com/mpv-player/mpv), this library can handle much more codecs and also online streaming play.

Comment: Thank you very much. How can I online streaming play with python-mpv?

Comment: my sample is [here](https://gitee.com/leimiemie/py-opus-play), but the best is following the github official documents.